# How can I combine together cells within the same raster in ArcGIS 10.2?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, attribute-joins, land-cover, combine

I have a raster displaying Land Cover data for the UK at a cell size of 25m. The cells are currently categorised as one of 24 different types of land cover. Some of these are irrelevant to me, and others could be combined to have the same effect but make the map simpler. How can I join together 2 of these land cover categories within a single raster so they're effectively listed as a single land cover type?

Comment: In ArcMap, you want to look into the Reclassify tool. It requires the Spatial Analyst extension.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the reclassify tool. 
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/reclassify.htm